# установка ComboBoxItem в качестве SelectedItem у ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Не срабатывает свойство IsSelected у ComboBoxItem. В чем причина?

С#:

```
       ComboBoxItem cbItemTrue = new ComboBoxItem();
        cbItemTrue.Content = "Исправлена";            
        cbItemTrue.Tag = true;

        ComboBoxItem cbItemFalse = new ComboBoxItem();
        cbItemFalse.Content = "Не исправлена";
        cbItemFalse.Tag = false;

        if (obj) cbItemTrue.IsSelected = true;
        else cbItemFalse.IsSelected = true;

        return new List<ComboBoxItem>() { cbItemTrue, cbItemFalse};
```

XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Height="145" Width="875" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>                        
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Исправление" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Corrected, Converter={StaticResource CorrectConverter}}" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

Comment: а что за метод?  у которого вызывается    return new List<ComboBoxItem>() { cbItemTrue, cbItemFalse};

Comment: Ужас :-) Кто же так `WPF` использует?

Comment: @FoggyFinder хехе я только догнал. что он в конвертере ItemSource формирует, напомнило https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynlbxcyotoo

Comment: Тут есть одна проблема. Когда вы задаете у `ComboBox` свойство `ItemSource`, он подтягивает коллекцию и каждый элемент упаковывает.... ВНИМАНИЕ!!! В ComboBoxItem! :) А у вас сама коллекция типа `ComboBoxItem`. Смекаете? Получается ваш `ComboBoxItem` внутри сгенерированного `ComboBoxItem`. поэтому свойство `IsSelected` помечается у сгенерированного. Короче это не так надо делать. Если уж вы решили наговнокодить, то делайте это до конца и пихайте вашу коллекцию `ComboBoxItem` прямо в `ComboBox.Items` в коде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда выбор стоит между "Исправлена/Не Исправлена" напрашивается использование `CheckBox`, но если очень хочется...

[image: Внешний вид приложения]

Тестовый класс такой

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrected { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}-{Name}, Исправлено:{IsCorrected}";
    }

    public static List<TestClass> GetListTestClasses()
    {
        List<TestClass> result = new List<TestClass>();

        char sign = 'A';

        TestClass testClass = null;
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++, sign++)
        {
            testClass = new TestClass()
            {
                Id = i,
                Name = sign.ToString()
            };

            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                testClass.IsCorrected = true;
            }

            result.Add(testClass);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Связь между `MainWindow` & `MainViewModel`

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Связь между свойством-коллекцией, свойством-выбранный-элемент

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElementFirstList}"
```

Пример одного из столбцов

```
<ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id"
                                Width="30"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
```

Пример (важно!) столбца с `ComboBox` (обратите внимание, что используется `SelectedIndex` для выбора элемента)

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Исправление"
                                Width="135">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="120"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ListStatusIsCorrected, ElementName=window}"
                                SelectedIndex="{Binding IsCorrected, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Для работы преобразования `Boolean <-> Int32` используем такой конвертер

```
public class BooleanToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool corrected = (bool)value;

        if (corrected)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int corrected = (int)value;

        if (corrected == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Конвертер выставлен для подключения как статический ресурс так

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToIntConverter x:Key="Converter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Целиком вью-модель выглядит так

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    //ctor
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //заполняем коллекцию тестовыми данными
        FirstList = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>(TestClass.GetListTestClasses());
    }

    //для показа MessageBox
    public IMessageService MessageService { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstList}" 
    /// </summary>
    private ObservableCollection<TestClass> _FirstList;
    public ObservableCollection<TestClass> FirstList
    {
        get { return _FirstList; }
        set
        {
            _FirstList = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FirstList)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElementFirstList}"
    /// </summary>
    private TestClass _SelectedElementFirstList;
    public TestClass SelectedElementFirstList
    {
        get { return _SelectedElementFirstList; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedElementFirstList = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedElementFirstList)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ListStatusIsCorrected, ElementName=window}"
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> ListStatusIsCorrected { get; private set; }
        = new List<string>() { "Не исправлена", "Исправлена" };


    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка отображения информации об элементе
    /// </summary>
    private RelayCommand _ShowInfoAboutTestClassCommand;
    public RelayCommand ShowInfoAboutTestClassCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _ShowInfoAboutTestClassCommand = _ShowInfoAboutTestClassCommand ??
              new RelayCommand(OnShowInfoAboutClass);
        }
    }
    private void OnShowInfoAboutClass()
    {
        //если элемент не выбран в ListView
        if (SelectedElementFirstList == null) return;

        //показываем данные выделенного элемента
        string message = SelectedElementFirstList.ToString();
        MessageService.ShowInfo(message);
    }
}
```