# Обработка нажатия по ItemControl и определение по какому именно элементу был совершен клик. MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем доброго времени суток!
Крик души! Осталось реализовать две фичи, но бьюсь над ними уже пару дней.

Буду приводить примеры, на примере тестового проекта, чтобы не грузить лишними настройками и строками кода.

Имеется у меня ObservableCollection. Я подписываю ее на ItemControl.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection}">
```

Далее идет шаблон этого ItemControl

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>                        
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Number}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Вопрос в следующем, как подписать команду на клик, по какому-нибудь из элементов ItemControla, и как определить по какому именно элементу был клик.

TestClacc - это простейший класс с двумя полями: Number и Name.

Comment: Вам нужен именно клик по элементу или достаточно выделенного элемента?

Comment: Создайте свойство типа вашего класса и привяжите его к `SelectedItem` у `ItemsControl`

Comment: Вот здесь подробный пример на похожий [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/613551/222542)

Comment: @sp7 для меня главное получить номер элемента, например в коллекции 10 элементов, пользователь нажимает на 4, и мне нужно получить это значение.

Comment: @Bulson Благодарю!
А можно еще примеры? или более конкретно рассказать? Просто не нашел у ItemsControl свойство SelectedItem

Понимаю, что наглею, но уже давно бьюсь над эти, тк руководство хочет именно так. И это одна из последних фич, для выпуска тестовой версии проекта.

Comment: Не, вы куда-то упорно лезете на низкий уровень. Зачем вам клик? И скорее всего вам нужен не индекс элемента, а сам элемент.

Comment: @VladD , к сожалению на домашнем ноуте нет рабочего проекта.

В коллекции у меня хранятся расшифрованные события одного устройства. При клике на одно из этих событий, в другой View должны появиться подробные данные об этом событии:дата, время, пояснение и тд. Для меня важно определить по какому из элементов этого ItemControla пользователь нажал, что бы передать это событие в нужный View/

Comment: Угу, классический master/detail view. Тогда первый совет @Bulson именно то, что вам надо.

Comment: @VladD , а будет ли оправдан переход с ItemsControl на ListBox?
Реализация упростится и переход быстрый.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Да, именно это написал в ответе.

Comment: @Bulson , признателен и благодарен за помощь и примеры!

Comment: @VladD , благодарю вас за помощь и советы!

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Comment: @VladD , теперь смогу с спокойной душой лечь спать) а с самого утра побегу реализовывать все ваши наставления)

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Удачи! Спрашивайте ещё, если что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `ListBox` вместо `ItemsControl`, в нём есть встроенное понятие выделенного элемента.

Ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTestClass}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<!-- тут должны отобразиться подробности выделенного элемента -->
<Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedTestClass}">
    ...
</Grid>
```